# Is there any function like checksum in Oracle

Tags: oracle, checksum

I need to calculate the checksum of some columns. The built-in function **checksum** is used to calculate the checksum in Microsoft SQL Server.

Is there any built-in function **checksum** in **Oracle**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Oracle's STANDARD_HASH function.

> Oracle's STANDARD_HASH function "computes a hash value for a given
>   expression" (see the documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions183.htm#SQLRF55647)). Use the checksums in the WHERE
>   clause of the UPDATE (in the MERGE statement).

You might do something like this:

```
-- 2 tables
create table table1 as
select 1 id, 1 a1, 1 b1, 1 c1, 1 d1, 1 e1, 1 f1 from dual;

create table table2 as
select 2 id, 2 a2, 2 b2, 2 c2, 2 d2, 2 e2, 2 f2 from dual;
```

and then calculate a SHA256 checksum:

```
SELECT
  STANDARD_HASH ( T.id || T.a1 || T.b1 || T.c1 || T.d1 || T.e1 || T.f1, 'SHA256' )
AS my_hash_1
FROM table1 T ;
```

- MY_HASH_1 0x2558A34D4D20964CA1D272AB26CCCE9511D880579593CD4C9E01AB91ED00F325

and

```
SELECT 
  STANDARD_HASH ( T.id || T.a2 || T.b2 || T.c2 || T.d2 || T.e2 || T.f2, 'SHA256' ) 
AS my_hash_2 
FROM table2 T ;
```

- MY_HASH_2
  0xCC2E018AA6EB9612CCD027BBDCDC9B8C8D351789F14CAE4D688A876C18938235

This will tell you if your records are the same or different (well, to a very high probablity! :-) ).

With STANDARD_HASH, you get to choose your hashing algorithm. You might want to be careful about your choice - MD5 is much less processor intensive than SHA256. If security is **not** a major concern, you might want to use that instead? See the fidddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b53547bab882954d104cf86e0211f574) for more.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49351935/how-to-calculate-checksum-in-oracle/49352350#49352350) for the excellent question, and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49352774/470530) (same thread) for the excellent answer, both of which I (shamelessly!) lifted to answer this question. I felt that the thread and answer were both good enough to merit a place on dba.stackexchange!